# gstreamer: pass frame PTS in command line API

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

Currently I have a setup like this.

```
my-app | gst-launch-1.0 -e fdsrc ! \
    videoparse format=GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_BGR width=640 height=480 ! \
    videoconvert ! 'video/x-raw, format=I420' ! x265enc ! h265parse ! \
    matroskamux ! filesink location=my.mkv
```

From `my-app` I am streaming raw BGR frame buffers to gst. How can I also pass presentation timestamps (PTSs) for those frames? I have somewhat full control over `my-app`. I can open other pipes to gst from it.

I know I have the option to use gstreamer C/C++ API or write a gstreamer plugin, but I was trying to avoid this.

Comment: is my-app, pumping out gst-buffer in that case you just set the pts of the buffer before pumping out, as you are already do a videoparse everything should be taken care. For example the following pipleine the pts is set (gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc do-timestamp=true ! fakesink dump=true | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! videoparse ! identity silent=false ! fakesink)

Comment: The above comment is not true. `fakesink` will dump the raw image data only discarding any DTS/PTS or other `GstBuffer` data and `videoparse` will also only handle raw video data without any other information. The `gdp` plugin is meant to handle these types use cases.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch thanks for correcting me, the pts were added by the videoparse element!

Comment: Yeah your example is tricky as probably videotestsrc and videoparse generate the same timestamps by default configurations looking like they transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can set a `framerate` for the `videoparse` element. You can also try `do-timestamp=true` for the `fdsrc` - maybe it requires a combination of both.

If you have the PTS in `my-app` you would probably need to wrap buffers and PTS in a real `GstBuffer` and use `gdppay` and `gdpdepay` as payload between the link.

For example if your `my-app` would dump the images in the following format:
https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/blob/master/docs/random/gdp
(not sure how recent this info document is)

You could receive the data with the following pipeline:

```
fdsrc ! gdpdepay ! videoconvert ! ..
```

No need for resolution and format either as it is part of the protocol too. And you will have PTS as well if set.

If you can use GStreamer lib in `my-app` you could some soome pipeline like this:

```
appsrc ! gdppay ! fakesink dump=true
```

And you would push your image buffers with PTS to the appsink.

See https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/master/gst/gdp for some examples how `gdp` is used as a protocol.

Comment: I do have the timestamps in `my-app` that I want to pass to gstreamer.

Comment: It looks like `do-timestamp=true` is not documented in `fdsrc` plugin. So if you have it, as soon as the frame arrives it will get timestamped with the current time? This looks like it is not very useful if you have pressure on the encoder, as this would make the gsteamer pipeline not able to keep up and when the OS buffer gets full it will block.

Comment: Yes, it is not quite clear what these PTS represent in your case - if you are realtime, constant frame rate etc.

Comment: @Sogartar  to remove the blocking  when there is too much pressure on OS you can add a  queue, which holds the  buffers for some X amount of time (fdsrc ! queue min-threshold-buffers=0 min-threshold-bytes=0 min-threshold-time=X ! ..). note X is in nanoseconds